# How to refresh the store/model every few seconds?

Tags: extjs

i have a grid panel (store and models are associated with it) where i am displaying all the data in row wise manner.The column of grid panel consist of action column where if person clicks, it opens a new form in tab style and user fills the data and it got saved in db. i want is, how the store should be refreshed every few second so that this data should also be displayed in the grid panel automatically. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could handle this, personally I would just reload the store when the form has closed to reload any updates rather than just reloading constantly.

The code below shows how you could use a [TaskRunner](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner) in ExtJs to reload the store every x seconds, You could also add a setTimeout in the load event of the store so that every time the store loads you schedule it to load again in x seconds.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'characters'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function() {
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner(),
            task = runner.start({
                run: function() {
                    store.reload();
                },
                interval: 3000
            });

        // IMPORTANT: Dont forget to call stop at a logical point.
        runner.stop();
    }
});
```

There is also a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/glh) containing this code that you can play around with.

If I had to go with the SetTimeout or TaskRunner options for this I would likely initialize them in the render event of the parent panel/container and listen for the beforeDestroy event to stop them running.